# Unable to enter credit card payment information

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I just noticed that I'm unable to enter credit card payment information (card number, expiration date, CVV) when going through the Drupal Commerce checkout processing using the Square Connect payment gateway. This was working fine in the past; I'm not sure when it stopped working but it might be related to the newest Commerce Core release on 19 October 2022. The fields are there, but I can't enter text in any of the text boxes. They're blank and read-only. What might have changed, and how can I fix it?

These are the modules I'm using:

- Commerce Core 8.x-2.32 (released 19 October 2022)
- Commerce Square Connect 8.x-1.5 (released 13 April 2022)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an API deprecation by Square that the module was not prepared for in advance. Please test the following patch and comment on the issue if it works for you. Thanks!

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_square/issues/3231283#comment-14772813

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! I've added some comments to the issue.